# SML: Combining Two Lists

Tags: functional-programming, sml

I have the following function for combining two lists into one.  It's *supposedly* of type:

```
@ : 'a list * 'a list -> 'a list

fun @ (nil, k) = k
    | @ (x::l, k) = x :: @(l,k);
```

Let's say we have two lists: `[1, 2, 3]` and `[4, 5, 6]`.  If I call:

```
@([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])

1::@([2, 3], [4, 5, 6])

1::2::@([3], [4, 5, 6])

1::2::3::@(nil, [4, 5, 6])
```

But here we reach the base case and our `@` call returns the list `[4, 5, 6]`, yielding:

```
1::2::3::[4, 5, 6]
```

which is obviously not what I want.  Is the function definition correct or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I don't understand the question. *Why* is `1::2::3::[4, 5, 6]` not what you want? That's the correct result if `@` is meant to be an append function. What do you want?

Comment: Seems like maybe you are confusing`1::2::3::[4,5,6]` (which is just `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`) and  `[1,2,3,[4,5,6]]`. SML's type system doesn't allow for this last expression to be formed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes your function definition is correct.
`::` or *Cons* as it is called in Lisp and other functional programming languages is used for creating lists. It takes a value and a list (which may be empty) and creates a new list with the former prepended to the latter. So for example `42::[17, 23]` equals `[42, 17, 23]`.
Cons is right associative which means that your list
`1::2::3::[4,5,6]`
can be written as
`(1::(2::(3::[4,5,6])))`
and by successive reductions we get
`[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

Comment: Nit: `42::[17, 23]` does not evaluate to `[42, 17, 23]`, it *is* `[42, 17, 23]`, just written differently. List notation is just sugar for `::`.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg is this true for all languages that have cons or are you referring specifically to SML?

Comment: it is true for all FPLs I'm aware of, including SML, OCaml, Haskell (using `:`). If it wasn't the case then `::` would not be a constructor, and you could not use it to pattern-match a list, for example.